# How to make a webpage open up in a colorbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colorbox

im trying to open a different webpage as a colorbox but i cant seem to figure it out.

Below is the webpage i want to open when a person clicks on the image.

```
<div class="album py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="projects" class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 shadow-sm">
        <a href="project1.html" id="yourlink"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/mockup.png" alt="iPhone Mockup">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the script i did.

```
<script>
  "use strict";
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourlink').colorbox();
  });
</script>
```

This is my first time trying to use colorbox so its a little confusing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

colorbox has a configuration atrtibute called "html" where you can provide html code for it to show. For example:

```
var code = $('div.py-5').html();
$('#yourlink').colorbox({html: code});
```

If you can modify the html to show, you could also check the colorbox examples as they include an inline HTML example.

Edit: Here's a working example:

```js
var button = $("#clickme");

$(document).ready(function() {
 var code = $("#myContent").html();
 $("#clickme").colorbox({ "html": code })
});
```

```css
#myContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <title>Colorbox Examples</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <style rel="https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Hello World from the content.</p>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#none" id="clickme">Click me</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var code = $('div.py-5').html();
                $.colorbox({ href: code, iframe: true, innerWidth: 645, innerHeight: 509});
});

Comment: i tired doing the code above but nothing happens when i try it out. I'm not sure whats wrong.